# Getting rid of Autorelease pools

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, memory-management

I have an iPhone app that is crashing without explanation. After reading that Autorelease pools are ill advised for iOS I went to search them out in my app and have discovered three (including one in main.m and one in a NSThread).

What exactly do I need to do to eliminate these from my code?

Thanks!

---

EDIT 1

I am printing, but can't see why it's crashing. Basically I start a thread which calls a method and then the app crashes. The first thing the method is set to do is to print to the console (with no values, just to show that the call worked), but it doesn't even get to that point. Very strange. Any ideas on how I could debug this?

Comment: The autorelease pools are not your problem.  You need them actually.

Comment: Autorelease pools are required. Check and see if you are starting a task on another thread. You most likely will need an autorelease pool there depending on what you are doing.

Comment: did you found them in your code-app? and who put them in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where did you read that autorelease pools are ill advised?  I suggest you find some better sources of information.

Granted, you shouldn't be using autorelease pools haphazardly, and improper usage can cause problems, but certain situations *require* them.  At a minimum, that one you found in `main.m` should be there.  As should the one you found in your `NSThread`.  It is very unlikely that they are responsible for your crash, assuming that your code is using them correctly.

When you application crashes do you get anything at all when running in debug mode?  Any stack trace in the console, or log messages talking about memory warnings?  Does the app crash randomly or only after performing a particular action?  More information and/or code would be useful.

Comment: The debugger isn't printing anything. Just 'program exited with status value 1.' See EDIT 1. :)

Comment: @Eric Brotto - It sounds like your code is fairly small at this point.  If so, code you post some of it to give us a better idea of what you are trying to do, and how you are trying to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Autoreleases that are part of the iOS templates are not the problem. Autorelease pools are often necessary, and may not be why your app is crashing.

To address your problem

1. Add NSLog statements to your code to try and find out where your app is crashing
2. Use Instruments to detect memory problems and leaks
3. You may be over releasing objects. Here's an excellent [Memory Management Guide.](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/)

Answer (score 0):

Autorelease in main function and in new thread is required as per apple documentation. because when app launch some memory is reserved for launching the app. and if autorelease pool rempoved from the main function memory leak will be shown by simulator same in creating new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Autorelease pools are required and the presence of an Autorelease pool is certainly not your problem. If your app is failing without a helpful log, try setting a breakpoint on exceptions.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html